# Error: no match for call to (std::string{aka std::basic_string<char>})(const char[5])'

Tags: c++, file, error-handling, ofstream

So im coding a small if situation in my program where it gets user input and uses that input to make a text file using the info from the user input, then makes an fstream object to write to that file later. and for some reason i get an error that says

`"no match for call to (std::string{aka std::basic_string<char>})(const char[5])'"`

with another error saying

`"invalid user defined conversation from 'std::ofstream{aka std::basic_ofstream<char>}'to 'const char*'[-fpermissive]"`

now i don't really understand anything about these 2 errors so i would really appreciate some help, for more info here is the chunk of code the errors took place in

```
if(choosingThis==1)
            {
                cout <<"Name your database"<< endl;
                
                string naming;
                cin >> naming;
                
                ofstream newie(naming); //first error took place here 

                ofstream newFile; 
                newFile.open(newie); //next error error took place here 
                
                cout <<"wanna insert some data?"<< endl;
                
                string yup;
                cin >> yup;
                
                bool probably;
                
                if(yup=="yes")
                {
                    probably=true;
                }
                else if(yup=="no")
                {
                    probably=false;
                }
                
                if(probably==true)
                {
                    cout <<"insert your data"<< endl;
                    
                    string dataforThenew;
                    cin >> dataforThenew;
                    
                    getline(cin,dataforThenew);
                    
                    fstream dataPasser;
                    dataPasser.open(newie);
                    
                    dataPasser << dataforThenew;
                    
                    cout <<"wanna go back?"<< endl;
                    
                    string yes;
                    cin >> yes;
                    
                    if(yes=="yes")
                    {
                        main();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        cout <<"ok"<< endl;
                        
                        system("pause");
                        return 0;
                    }
```

Comment: In both cases you pass a `std::string` as a parameter, but it should be rather `const char *` instead. Try: `newbie.c_str()`.

Comment: @vahancho in the second case he uses an ofstream to open an ofstream not a string. A string is a valid parameter in an ofstream constructor, so I do not know why he gets this error

Comment: @RoQuOTriX, ah, right!

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you are using an old compiler. `std::string` can be used to initialize `std::ostream` since C++11. Depending on compiler, the flag to enable C++11 would be `-std=c++11` (gcc and clang) or `/std:c++11` (MSVC). This should fix first error.
If for some reason you are stuck with compiler that doesn't support C++11, you can extract C-style string from `std::string`:

```
ofstream newie(naming.c_str());
```

---

Second error is because you are trying to do something that doesn't make sense. You want to `open()` an fstream using another fstream. You cannot have two output streams to the same file. You need to explain what you trying to do here before we can suggest alternatives.
In this snippet, you are not using either `newie` nor `newFile`, so perhaps you simply wanted `fstream dataPasser(naming);`?

---

One more thing: calling `main()` directly is Undefined Behviour, you are not allowed to do that. You need to find another way to restart your procedure (a loop perhaps?).